# A circle on the plane

Tags: geometry, circles, parametric

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parametric Equation of a Circle in 3D Space?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/73237/parametric-equation-of-a-circle-in-3d-space)

I know that, for example, if a circle is on a plane with counter-clockwise orientation,  and with center $(a,b)$ and radius $R$, it has parametrization

$$r(t)=(a + R \cos{t};b + R \sin{t}) \quad 0 \leq t \leq 2\pi$$

and with clockwise orientation

$$r(t)=(a + R \sin{t},b + R \cos{t}).$$

Also, I know of forms of circle parametrization if it lies on horizontal plane $z=c$ and center $O(a,b,c)$, or if it is located on the plane $x=c$, I know how to parametrize the circle in this case.  I am interested in what happens if the circle does not lie in any plane parallel to the coordinate planes?

Comment: "i am interested what if f the circle does not lie in any plane parallel to the coordinate planes" - then you use an appropriate rotation matrix on the parametric equations for a circle.

Comment: what kind of appropriate matrix?

Comment: Do you know how rotation matrices are built up?

Comment: generally no,i now some kind of  rotation matrices,but how  they are built up,i dont know

Comment: and also why  did you downvote my question?

Comment: I did no such thing; why did you automatically assume that I was your downvoter? In any event, I am advicing you to read up a bit on rotation matrices first, and then we can talk.

Comment: so it means ,that someone can't understand question and just does it without any thinking,no you can  tell me ,dont worry if i  would not understand it.please tell me how  can i solve  this task?use any concrete  example if you would like

Comment: @dato: You may have been downvoted because of the unclear writing. It would help to use (more) punctuation so that your question is not a single sentence.

Comment: @Théophile  maybe ,because my native language is georgian and not english,you are right

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let $\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v}$ be any two orthonormal vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$, let $\mathbf{a} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and let $R > 0$ be a positive real number. Then the circle of radius $R$ with centre $\mathbf{a}$ lying in the plane through $\mathbf{a}$ which is parallel to $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{v}$ is given by

$$\mathbf{r}(t) = \mathbf{a} + (R\cos t)\mathbf{u} + (R\sin t)\mathbf{v}$$

where $\mathbf{r}(t)$ denotes the locus of the points on the circle.

So given a plane $\Pi \subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$, calculate $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{v}$ and substitute into the above.

Comment: $u$ and $v$ we can calculate using this parametrizations,which i have written above or?

Comment: @dato: I don't really understand what you're asking. You can calculate $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{v}$ by looking at the specification of the plane you want your circle to be in. There are a number of ways of specifying a plane, which I'm sure you've come across already.

Comment: aa ok ok thanks very much,just one question $a$ in this case is a scalar right?i  dont want to mix,or it is vector?

Comment: It's a vector. It couldn't possibly be a scalar, because you can't add a scalar to a vector. Here, $\mathbf{a}$ is the centre of the circle, so you could write, say, $\mathbf{a} = (a,b,c)$ if you wanted to. (At least, you could when working in 3 dimensions.)

Comment: thanks very much for answer

Answer (score 3):

(Clive beat me by a few minutes, but I leave my answer here anyway, as it addresses aspects not covered by Clive.)

Assume your circle $\gamma$ has center ${\bf p}\in{\mathbb R}^3$. The plane $\Pi$ in which the circle lies has to be given somehow. If the plane is given in the form ${\bf n}\cdot{\bf x}=\rho$, where $\rho={\bf n}\cdot {\bf p}$, then we first have to provide ourselves with two mutually orthogonal unit vectors ${\bf e}_i$ which "span $\Pi$" or, to be exact, are orthogonal to ${\bf n}$. The first of these vectors can be obtained by normalizing the vector ${\bf e}_1':=(-n_2,n_1,0)$ (which is orthogonal to ${\bf n}$). *Normalizing* means replacing the vector ${\bf e}_1'$ by the unit vector
$${\bf e}_1:={{\bf e}_1'\over\bigl|{\bf e}_1'\bigr|}$$ which points in the same direction. The second vector ${\bf e}_2$ is then obtained by normalizing the vector ${\bf e}_2':={\bf n}\times{\bf e}_1$.

After these preparatory steps it is easy to write down a parametric representation of $\gamma$:
$$\gamma:\quad t\mapsto{\bf p}+R\cos(t){\bf e}_1+R\sin(t){\bf e}_2\qquad(0\leq t\leq 2\pi)\ .$$

Comment: sorry normalize vector $e_1=(-n_2,n_1,0)$ what does mean?which vector we are normalizing